# Where can I buy a 4x4 Ghost Cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I have the standard 3x3 Ghost Cube, and I would like to get more sizes. On [this page](https://ruwix.com/twisty-puzzles/3x3x3-rubiks-cube-shape-mods-variations/ghost-cube/) on ruwix.com there is an image for 2x2 through 7x7 Ghost Cubes, but I can't figure out where I can buy them.

Does anyone know how I can get at least the 4x4 Ghost Cube?

Comment: https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/puzzle-stores-webshops-around-the-world-where-to-buy-rubiks-cubes/

Comment: I checked every one of those stores and couldn't find anything except the 2x2 and 3x3. No 4x4 or above.

Comment: Are shopping questions on-topic?

Comment: I feel like obtaining a puzzle is a fundamental part of puzzling... so I don't see why it wouldn't be on topic.

Comment: found this http://www.ziicube.com/Exponent/4x4x4/Moyu-444-KingKong but no 4x4 ghost.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's [shopping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed) - yes, getting a puzzle in the first place is part of puzzling, but such questions' answers are prone to outdatedness and spamming.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a 4x4 Ghost Cube, but I sold it a year ago when I needed the money. As of yet, they aren't mass-produced. There are only one or two people out there who know how to make them. Virust Cube used to be the one who made them, and he was the one who made mine in 2017, but he stopped making puzzles in 2018. You should look up Messer Puzzles in Facebook, he's one of the people (if not the only one) who currently makes them. Expect to pay over 200 USD for one. If you're willing to pay even more, some people may be willing to create and 3D-print one for you. It's not cost-efficient to make just one this way, so most people probably won't want to do it unless you offer them a large sum of money (maybe $500+).